# Swift: Why is the init?(length length: Int) NSMutableData's initializer failable?

Tags: swift, swift2, nsdata, initializer, failable

The memory allocation can fail, but I think Swift doesn't handle that cases.
The code on [github](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/NSData.swift) calls a non failable initializer

```
public convenience init?(length: Int) {
    let memory = malloc(length)
    self.init(bytes: memory, length: length, copy: false) { buffer, amount in
        free(buffer)
    }
}
```

EDIT:
The code is from the native-Swift Foundation framework coming in Swift 3.

Comment: Interesting question. You might get better answers at one of the mailing lists at https://swift.org/community/#mailing-lists.

Comment: It looks like they just reserved it for a future possibility to fail without changing the interface afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the swift-users list:

"Swift’s policy on memory allocation failure is that fixed-size object  allocation is considered to be a runtime failure if it cannot be handled.  OTOH, APIs that can take a variable and arbitrarily large amount to allocate should be failable.  NSData falls into the later category." -Chris

Comment: So it's failable but it never fails? If the allocation fails what happens?

Comment: It fails on mac. NSMutableData(length: 1000000000000000) returns nil

Comment: I get Chris' point but my doubt is: can it **actually** fail? Let's say `malloc` fails and memory is `.None`, you'll probably get a crash when trying to access that data (i.e bad access).

Comment: Using the new Swift-Foundation? That's a bit intriguing to me considering the call is delegated to a non-failable initializer.

Comment: No, not with the Swift-Foundation. With the current Xcode and swift 2.2 it returns nil and write some error message to the stdout.
$R0: NSMutableData? = nil

Comment: It’s worth noting that `Data.init(capacity:Int)` is non-failable as of https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/pull/538.